# How to enable SSR support for 'styled-components' for third party library(NextJS+styled-components+babel+component library)

Tags: next.js, babeljs, styled-components

styled components for SSR needs to be transpiled with special plugins such as (babel-plugin-styled-components or typescript-plugin-styled-components)

https://styled-components.com/docs/tooling#serverside-rendering

Using so, it adds the deterministic component ID to each of the component to avoid classname collision and thus to avoid hydration issues such as **Classname didn't match**

my babel.config.json in NextJS app is set to,

```
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": [["styled-components", { "ssr": true, "displayName": false, "minify": true }]]
}
```

this takes care of enabling SSR support for the styled components which I have created in the app(./src/components) **BUT**

I'm consuming a third-party component library(@org/carousel) which is **not** maintained by me so I have no control over its build & publish process.

Since NextJS clearly ignores transpiling node_modules, so I have looked at **next-transpiled-modules** with the following setup in **next.config.js**, hoping that it would that support

```
const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')(['@org/carousel']);

module.exports = withTM();
```

**Yet**, in my build, I don't see the addition of deterministic ID for that component.

**Gist:**
node_modules/@org/carousel/build/index.js has **styled.div()** but we need it as styled.div.withConfig({componentId:'sc-someId'})

1. **Am I in the right direction?**
2. **Can we transpile an ES5 compliant module again? (@org/carousel was already transpiled before publish)**
3. **Are there any other ways to address this issue?**

Any thoughts/ideas/suggestions are greatly appreciated!